# How to access the name of a column which is a number through a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

Problem : I can't select the column of a dataframe through a variable if the column is a number. Example:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6)) #Create a dataframe

colnames(df) <- c("99","66") #Column names are numbers (let's say the id of something)
```

I can do this:

```
print(df$`99`[1])
```

But I can't do this:

```
k <- 99
print(df$`k`[1])
```

The reason I'm trying to use a variable to access the column name is that I want to loop over the column names:

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  df$"i"
  df[,i]
}
```

Comment: Convert it to character to avoid getting evaluated as numeric index `df[[as.character(k)]][1]` .  If you use `df[[k]]`, it looks for the 99th column

Comment: To add to @akrun's point, generally we only use `$` interactively, or if the column name is somehow always the same. `[[` is the tool if you are accessing data frame columns programmatically.

Comment: Remove `df$"i"` from your `for` loop and it should work as it is because `colnames(df)` are already of type `character`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do-

```
> k=99
> df[[paste0(k)]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Just for more clarification on your `for loop` -

```
cols <- c(99,66)
for(i in 1:length(cols))
{
   print(df[[paste0(cols[i])]])
}
```

Output-

```
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 4 5 6
```